# Sitecore item will not go into edit mode; any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

I have several Sitecore items (whose template is connected to an approval workflow) that will not go into Edit mode when clicking "Edit" from the "Review" tab. The same workflow is used elsewhere on the site successfully (the site is more than 3 years old), but clicking Edit in this case doesn't seem to affect the workflow state.

I've turned on verbose logging, which provides a lot of detail, but nothing to indicate any error conditions. I've been comparing how this template is configured with other "working" templates for a couple of days and everything looks Kosher, but surely I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: The item(s) in question are imported by a data provider, and I've confirmed that for some reason Sitecore is not setting the "Workflow" and "State" system standard fields with a default value. That appears to be at least part of the issue.

EDIT 2: Followed the steps in this thread http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=45991 to use Sitecore Rocks to update all of the items to the correct Workflow State, but the update did not stick. For some reason workflow changes are not persisted for imported items.

EDIT 3: Clicking the Edit dropdown button under the Home tab displays the message "The item is currently not part of a workflow."

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032040/adding-a-workflow-to-an-existing-item-in-sitecore-6-5

Answer (score 0):

Standard values set correctly?  Only have *one* Standard Values item for this template?

Generally, almost every time I run into a situation where X works on certain items, but not on others... it's a permissions issue.  You've tested this as an Administrator I hope?

Sorry my suggestions are so vague, but it's hard to be specific here.  We need some more information from you... When you click on Edit what exactly are you expecting to happen?  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Edit mode" here.  In Content Editor, all items are essentially in edit mode all the time... In my configuration, when I click on Edit, I am just locking the item.  It does not change workflow state or create a new version.

These items are coming from a data provider... is your data provider handling Lock/Unlock calls properly?  I know it's possible to use a data provider without implementing the entire Item API.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bryan. Workflows are ignored when editing as an admin, but even logged in as an admin I can't manually update the Workflow state of the item. In my configuration item fields are not read-only until you click Edit. Clicking Edit would normally make the fields editable, and allow the user to advance to the next workflow state (either "Submit" or "Cancel"). The issue is that clicking "Edit" has no affect.

Comment: The data provider is a framework provided by a Sitecore consulting firm that we've been using for around 3 years (the only thing we ever change are XML config files), so probably unlikely it's not handling lock/unlock calls properly.

Comment: Are you using this data provider for other item types that are working correctly?

Comment: How are Workflow and State persisted in the outside data source?  You use the word "import" and also "data provider", but in my mind these are two different things.  IMPORT implies that you are taking data from an outside system and moving it into storage as a Sitecore item (Saved in master DB).  Import implies a one-time action.  A DATA PROVIDER does not do this... rather it sits as a layer between Siteocre and a 3rd party system and provides access to outside data as if it was Sitecore Items.  Hence Workflow, State, etc. must be saved and communicated through the data layer.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: the data provider is also executed at periodic intervals (nightly, etc) as an import job. It inherits from DataProvider, so I should just call it that. It does work correctly for other items. I'm manually stepping through the code and haven't been able to find anything obvious.